# Typescript can't infer function generic type with parameters type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, inference

i have a very specific problem
consider this signature

```
public async createSubscriberChannel<
    T extends Messages.PubsubParams,
    K extends Messages.PubsubMessage<T>
  >(metadata: ChannelMetadata<T, K, TbNextgenQueue>, args: SubscriberArgs<T>)
```

and this call

```
const publisherChannel = await rabbitmqController.createPublisherChannel(
    new TaskCreatedMetadata(),
    {
      exchange: TbNextgenExchange.TASK_CREATED,
      exchangeOptions: {
        durable: false,
      },
    }
  );
```

with TaskCreatedMetadata

```
export class TaskCreatedMetadata extends ChannelMetadata<
  Messages.TaskCreatedParams,
  Messages.PubsubMessage<Messages.TaskCreatedParams>,
  TbNextgenQueue.TASK_CREATED
> {
  readonly queueName = TbNextgenQueue.TASK_CREATED;
}
```

now when i call the createSubscriberChannel function is not infering that T is of type Messages.TaskCreatedParams , is considering Messages.PubsubParams. I want that inference, is there any way to make it work as i expect ?

I am expecting to infer T generic using argument type

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a self-contained [mre] that we can paste into a standalone IDE to see what you're seeing. Any third-party types and values should either be replaced with native ones, or you should provide declarations for them.